# CrystalReports record selection formula with IN keyword

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

In my C# application I'm loading and displaying CrystalReport.

```
private ReportDocument _report;
_report = new ReportDocument();
var rptLocation = DownloadReportToTemp(reportName);
_report.Load(rptLocation);
_report.RecordSelectionFormula = "{Company.Id} IN [\"12\",\"15\"] AND (" + Environment.NewLine + _report.RecordSelectionFormula + Environment.NewLine + ")";
```

As You can see I'm loading report and adding some extra criteria to record selection formula.

This all works fine except fact that CrystalReports is changing my **IN** formula to multiple **OR** in SQL, inside query that I can see in profiler there is this part:

```
and ((Company.Id like @P1 or Company.Id like @P2)
```

For IN with two values that's fine, but if I add 4000 then whole query runs forever.

Can I change the way Crystal is interpreting **IN** or replace it with subquery?

I can't modify RPT files by hand, I can modify record selection formula

Comment: Can you write a stored procedure and have Crystal call it?

Comment: @TabAlleman thanks for suggestion, but as I wrote in my question I can't modify RPT files. All I can change are parameters values and record selection formula, I can't change data source (replace it with stored procedure).